# How to handle ServiceMode il fault state

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have followed this example to create a communication between a ASP.NET Website and a C# project: https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/

After some time of inactivity the service goes in fault state and I can't exchange data anymore:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException' in mscorlib.dll

This exception is raised when I try to send a message from the Website, like in the example:

```
service.SendMessage("Hi, I'm the client");
```

Is there a way to make the service permanently enabled? 
It will work on LAN and the webpage is a control interface that might send data every few hours.

### UPDATE

Here the server configuration:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class IServer : Interfaces.IService
    {
        public void Connect()
        {
            Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<Interfaces.ICallbackService>();
        }

        public static Interfaces.ICallbackService Callback { get; set; }

        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            MessageReceivedEventArgs args = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
            args.json = message;
            OnMessageReceived(this, args);
        }

        public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;
        protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }

    public class MessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string json;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a new connection for each request?

Comment: That's exactly the *workaround* I'm using right now! But I don't think it's a good practice...

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  In any way, an exception should cause your program to back off and start something (some section) anew. Keep it stateless amap.

Comment: Could you show configuration of the server part? Also, what is the instance context mode for the service?

Comment: @IgorLabutin: I've update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your service has single instance, then it might be OK to maintain permanent connection to it. Permanent connections are not good as they consume resources, but if you really want it, then you need to set `receiveTimeout` on both sides to `TimeSpan.Max`. In this way WCF will not close connection like it does now.

In your example code you need to replace `new NetNamedPipeBinding()` with `new NetNamedPipeBinding() { ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.Max }` in both client and server code.

According to the service code you do not suppose more than 1 client connected (because `Callback` is static field), but still be aware that if client disconnects, then `Callback` will look like it is valid, but if you try send something it will throw.

Comment: Yes, I will have only one client. Please, would you explain a bit more the last sentence? I'm not sure to understand correctly. Are you talking about when a client disconnects and then the server tries to send via Callback?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't see that you're using it now in the code sample you've posted. But if you do use it, then be aware that calling some callback method via `Callback` field may throw if client disconnects.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find any `ReceiveTimeout` property. Perhaps I'm looking at the wrong classes. Please, what class has this property?

Comment: How do you configure your endpoints? You either use config file or do it in C#. Could you show the code/config for both client and server, then I'll tell which property to update.

This is property of the binding, so you either need to specify your binding in config file explicitly or when you create binding in the code set its property.

Comment: You might find the link to the code in the first post. Actually I changed nothing about the endpoints configuration.

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation how to set receive timeout

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code. It seems to work, but I wonder how robust it is.

```
public bool CheckConnection()
{
    if (pipeFactory == null)
    {
        pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(new InstanceContext(_instance), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/ipc"));
    }

    try
    {
        switch (pipeFactory.State)
        {
            case CommunicationState.Faulted:
                pipeFactory.Abort();
                pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(new InstanceContext(_instance), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/ipc"));
                service = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
                service.Connect();
                break;

            case CommunicationState.Closed:
                service = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
                service.Connect();
                break;

            case CommunicationState.Created:
                service = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
                service.Connect();
                break;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        throw;
    }

    return pipeFactory.State == CommunicationState.Opened;
}
```

### UPDATE

This doesn't work. Even if the `pipeFactory.State` is `Opened` the following exception is raised after some time of inactivity:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at Interfaces.IService.SendMessage(String message)
>      at _Default.Submit1(String name, String surname, String country, String email, Boolean disclaimer1, Boolean disclaimer2) in Default.aspx.cs:line 99